# Viewing MySQL Account Resource Limits

Tags: mysql

Is there any way of viewing an account's remaining resources that are allocated to it? I setup an account that's allowed 7200 queries an hour. At any point, could I then run a query to find out how many remaining queries it's allowed?

MySQL must be storing this information somewhere as `FLUSH USER_RESOURCES;` will reset the counters however, I tried a few variants such as `SHOW USER_RESOURCES` and they don't seem to display anything. I've also hunted around information_schema and mysql tables.

Is it just not possible to retrieve that information?

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 3):

User resources are store in "mysql.user" table :

```
SELECT max_questions, 
       max_updates, 
       max_connections 
FROM   mysql.user 
WHERE  user = 'myuser'
AND    host = '%';
```

Max.

Comment: Sadly, on a shared server, the information might not be available (`SELECT command denied to user`).

Answer (score 0):

To get exact data, you may try enabling log (legacy as general-log). And rotate the log file every one hr. Develop a shell script to get the lines matching for your query and subtract it with 7200 returning value stays as your remaining queries. (NOTE: Ensure log file size shouldn't reduce server cpu much).